# Implementing Frontend User Login

Tags: authentication, frontend, bolt-cms

I love **Bolt CMS** and would like to continue using it, but I can't figure out how to implement a **Frontend User Login system**. Has anyone done this before? 
If so, how?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The extension clientlogin does Oauth logins with google, facebook, twitter github and more, maybe that is what you're looking for
http://extensions.bolt.cm/view/72df95ac-d890-4efc-83ff-da21184af676